# Java regex and matcher

Tags: java, regex

What i have did:

```
public static String cvtPattern(String str) {
    StringBuilder pat = new StringBuilder();
    int start, length;

    pat.append('^');
    if (str.charAt(0) == '\'') {    // double quoting on Windows
        start = 1;
        length = str.length() - 1;
    } else {
        start = 0;
        length = str.length();
    }
    for (int i = start; i < length; i++) {
        switch(str.charAt(i)) {
        case '*': pat.append('.'); pat.append('*'); break;
        case '.': pat.append('\\'); pat.append('.'); break;
        case '?': pat.append('.'); break;
        default:  pat.append(str.charAt(i)); break;
        }
    }
    pat.append('$');
    return new String(pat);
}
```

Then at my main:

```
//my args[0] is the string ".java"
pattern = Regex.cvtPattern(args[0]);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
System.out.println("Pattern: " +p.toString());
Matcher m = p.matcher(fileName);
if (m.matches()){
System.out.println("File to be added: "+currentFile.getName());
matchQueue.add(file);
            }
```

my input is .java and it will be compiled to ^.java$. How come when my file name is anything.java, it doesnt match? Where did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is wrong.`^.java$` will not match `anthing.java`.You need to quantify `.` to accept more.Your formation should be

```
^.*\.java$
```